# Create new dataframe with annual growth of a variable for specific period

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I struggle to create a new table with R (using dplyr) from the following one (dfx).
ID can be a geographical area. For each of them I have a value (Value) that change in time (Year).

```
library(dplyr)

ID<-c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3)
Year <-c(1960,1970, 1975, 1970, 1995, 1970, 1990, 2000, 2005)
Value<-c(2, 4.5, 6.2, 3.2, 7.8, 3.2, 4.6, 6.7, 8.9)
dfx<-data_frame(ID, Year, Value)
```

What i'd like to do is to calculate for each period the annual variation following the equation: `[(final value/starting value)^(1/number of years)-1]*100`.

This would give the following df

```
ID<-c(1,1, 2, 3,3,3)
Periods<-c("1960-1970", "1970-1975", "1970-1995", "1970-1990","1990-2000","2000-2005") 
annual_var<-c(8.44, 6.61, 3.62, 1.83, 3.83, 5.84)
dfy<-data_frame(ID, Periods, annual_var)
```

I cannot figure out what is the best strategy to follow. Could you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `ID`, `paste` the current and next `Year` together using `lead`, then calculate the `annual_var` using the formula given and ignore the last row in each group (`slice(-n())`) as the last Period would be empty.

```
library(dplyr)
dfx %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Periods = paste0(Year, "-", lead(Year)), 
     annual_var = ((lead(Value)/Value) ^ (1/(lead(Year) - Year)) - 1) * 100) %>%
  slice(-n()) %>%
  select(-Year, -Value)

#    ID   Periods   annual_var
#   <dbl> <chr>          <dbl>
#1    1. 1960-1970       8.45
#2    1. 1970-1975       6.62
#3    2. 1970-1995       3.63
#4    3. 1970-1990       1.83
#5    3. 1990-2000       3.83
#6    3. 2000-2005       5.84
```

Comment: That's great ! Exactly what i needed ! Thanks a lot Ronak !